# How can I create Motion titles with fixed-length transitions?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, motion

I'm using Motion to create text overlays for a video that I'm editing in Final Cut Pro X. Each time an overlay appears on the video, it uses a transition to slide into view and to slide out again when finished. I've created a custom title in Motion that behaves as follows: the text is visible for 7 seconds, with a transition lasting 10 frames at the start and end.

Here's my problem: sometimes I want the text to be visible for a different duration. If I add my custom title to the FCPX timeline, then change the duration of the title from 7 seconds to 14 seconds, the transitions take twice as long to complete. It looks silly! Is there any way that I can make a title whose start/end animation takes place over a fixed duration, but where the total duration of the title can be customized freely?

Comment: Is it still in the middle? If so you could make the title say, 20 seconds long and trim it in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*Build-In* and *Build-Out* markers](https://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.0/en/motion/usermanual/index.html#chapter=11%26section=17%26tasks=true). If you right click (or control-click) on the top of the timeline, you'll get a pop-up menu with an option to add a marker. When you add it, you'll get a green timeline marker. Double-click it to edit it and choose whether it's a mandatory or optional build-in marker. Everything before that should play at the same speed in FCPX as it does in Motion. The area between the build-in and build-out markers will stretch to fit, and everything after the build-out marker will play as it does in Motion.

Answer (score 0):

If the text stays in the same place in between the transitions, you can just freeze frame one of the middle frames for as long as you need.

Otherwise, you should probably re-render your title from Motion without the transitions. Then re-create the transitions in FCP as needed.